# Custom Commands for Nested Accordions via jQuery Tools Tabs Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-tools

I'm sure that because I've spent far too long in front of the LCDs today, and my patience (and search results) aren't doing so well at this point that I'm just not clinking thearly.

I'm hoping someone will be able to link some documentation, or just help with a solution to a requests to the following jQuery Tools Tab Accordion that I located, implemented and am mostly satisfied with.

[The original article link](http://sdevgame.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/multiply-nested-accordions-from-jquery-tools/)

Example code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/

So, I have a multi-level nested accordion functioning just like the example running using the package provided.  Therefore, it works exactly like the example with my styling.

What I would like is to be able to implement one of the following functions:

1. **Add a "Collapse All" link** - I'm not against allowing the user to be able to open multiple parent panes at the same time, but would like to provide an easy way to quickly close all of the levels.  Basically, a "reset" without reloading the page.
2. **Auto close expanded panes when another parent tab is opened** - This would only allow for one parent pane to be open at a time, and limit the potential for an excessive amount of open accordions within accordions within accordions, and so on.

I appreciate any assistance ahead of time.  My brain is fried after converting and compiling massive amounts of data sets to populate these accordions, and the link to the original jQuery Tool information page listed in the article is no longer available.  I assume this version is out-of-date.

Therefore, that does allow for optional replies directing me to an updated version of this simliar tool.  I like that not matter the level of the accordion it is always structured the same:

```
<div class="accordion">
   <h2>Level 1 Clickable Title</h2>
      <div class="pane">
         Accordion Content
            <div class="accordion">
               <h2>Level 2 Clickable Title</h2>
                  <div class="pane">
                     Nested Content
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Again, thanks in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is you should look into using the Accordion Widget.

[jqueryui.com/accordion/](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Shouldn't be to difficult to substitute in, although I haven't used it for crazy-nested accordions.  Maybe someone else can verify that for you.

Good luck!

Comment: I saw that after implementing this version. The post was created Jan 2011, so this is just old code. It's odd to me that this is referred to as "tabs", but it is an accordion. I don't understand the reasoning, but whatever.  It's old.

I may swap in accordion and hope it works the same once I complete the painful process of preparing the data set provided to me.

If anyone can confirm that this will work in the same manner as the example linked above I would appreciate the time it would save me testing it out.